# Como obtener elementos de una coleccion de otro usuario en firebase

Tags: reactjs, base-de-datos, firebase

estoy tratando de obtener los productos de una coleccion que tiene cada usuario en firebase. No logro obtener esa coleccion que pertenece a cada usuario en particular.
La idea es que al ingresar en el input el uid(de firebase) de cada usuario, pueda obtener los productos dentro de su coleccion. Las reglas de la firebase estan bien, cada usuario tiene permitido ver elementos de otras colecciones ajenas. Trate de hacerlo de distintas maneras y no pude, tampoco puedo obtener la coleccion si ingreso el mismo uid del mismo usuario que esta buscando esa la misma. No se cual puede ser el error, le pregunte la gpt y no me da un codigo muy distinto al que hice.
Esta es la ruta dentro de la db para que puedan ver como ejemplo
/users/FsMDaKtWr7ad8UdEAyujvk2te3X2/productos/fmHt2RgaUDPQ6SjT1Zzt

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { getFirestore, collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export function Proveedores() {
  const [uidProveedor, setUidProveedor] = useState("");
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState(null);
  const [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);

  const handleUidChange = (e) => {
    setUidProveedor(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (uidProveedor) {
      const db = getFirestore();
      const usuariosCollectionRef = collection(db, "users");
      const q = query(usuariosCollectionRef, where("uid", "==", uidProveedor));

      try {
        const usuariosSnapshot = await getDocs(q);

        if (usuariosSnapshot.size === 1) {
          const usuarioData = usuariosSnapshot.docs[0].data();
          setUsuario(usuarioData);
          
          const productosCollectionRef = collection(db, "productos", uidProveedor);

          const productosSnapshot = await getDocs(productosCollectionRef);
          const productosData = productosSnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
          setProductos(productosData);
        } else {
          setUsuario(null); 
          setProductos([]); 
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error al obtener el usuario:", error);
      }
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Buscar Productos por UID de Usuario</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Ingrese la UID del Usuario:
          <input type="text" value={uidProveedor} onChange={handleUidChange} />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Buscar Productos</button>
      </form>
      {usuario ? (
        <div>
          <h3>Usuario Encontrado:</h3>
          <p>Nombre: {usuario.nombre}</p>
          <p>Correo Electrónico: {usuario.email}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <p>No se encontró un usuario con la UID especificada.</p>
      )}
      {productos.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          <h3>Productos del Usuario:</h3>
          <ul>
            {productos.map((producto, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{producto.nombre}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```